# Standards for HTML access keys

Tags: usability, interaction-design, accessibility, html5

Wanted to see if anyone has done some research on standard HTML access key. I have notices after doing some research many sites including Apple have incorporated the accesskey="s" on its search box. I find this extreamly usable if used properly and wanted to get input from the community.

Comment: +1 And for an authoritative answer, see http://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the latest guidance is to not bother with them.  They often compete with other navigation aids, JAWS for example. I believe people like the BBC in the UK have dropped access keys, and I recently helped build a central government UK site without these access keys.

Comment: Yep. Too much conflict. For most situations there are better approaches to accessibility. Still potential to add skip to content links or similar where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no list of accepted accesskey delegations. [WebAIM say](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#standard) that both the UK and Canadian govermnents attempted it and they provide that list on their website. I notice "S" is used as "Skip navigation" there, not "Search" too. Wikipedia use "f" as their search accesskey.

In my state government there is also a standard, but that differs from the UK and Canadian model as well. I think the key is: if you are going to use accesskeys provide information on them for your users (usually a list in your accessibility statement). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is that there is are too many "standards" for any one to legitimately be *standard*.

There are a few useful write-ups [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html) and [here](http://clagnut.com/blog/193/), and note the age of the second. Not much has changed in nine years.